# MongoDB Connection EC2

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, amazon-ec2, bitnami

I just setup a MongoDB instance to be running in EC2 using the Bitnami MEAN stack. I am trying to connect to the MongoDB instance in my node application, but I don't know what the URL path would be.

I am familiar with paths that look like this:

```
mongodb://username:password@candidate.37.mongolayer.com:port/database
```

But am unclear how I would figure out what the equivalent path is for my EC2 instance. I found that there is a mongodb-27017.sock file in one of the directories, but the below didn't work.

```
mongodb://{USERNAME}:{PASSWORD}@{EC2LINK}/stack/mongodb/tmp/mongodb-27017.sock/{DATABASENAME}
```

Is there any way to figure out what the path is?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Make sure mongo service is running: `service mongod status`
2. [Make sure the port is open in the security group.](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/authorizing-access-to-an-instance.html) ([mongo defaults to 27017](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/default-mongodb-port/))
3. Use this connection URL (same as you're used to): `mongodb://{USERNAME}:{PASSWORD}@{EC2 INSTANCE IP / HOSTNAME}/{DATABASENAME}` . [See Examples](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/connection-string/#examples)

Note: changing the port would require specifying it in the connection string.

Comment: Thanks @Reut. 

I think my port is open. But I will double check. Right now I'm getting this error:
TypeError: Cannot read property 'databaseName' of null

Comment: That's a whole other problem. Does the connection work?

Comment: Also if this is the extension after my ec2link "/stack/mongodb/tmp/mongodb-27017.sock" is the port 27017?

Comment: The default port is 27017. You can double-check in the configuration file and change it using a flag (`--port`) or in the configuration file when starting `mongod`.

Comment: Awesome. Thanks. So this was my original link:

@{ec2.com}/stack/mongodb/tmp/mongodb-27017.sock/{DATABASE}

That clearly didn't work.

Comment: I'm getting mongod: unrecognized service when I run that command, but will look into it. Appreciate the help so far!

Comment: mongodb connection uri should contain EC2 hostname not socket file location.

Comment: I found that my issue had to do with bind_ip, but you helped me realize that  the correct path was indeed {AMAZONEC2LINK}:{PORT}/{DATABASE}, so for that I've chosen your response as the correct answer.

Comment: Hello, Do I need to create Elastic Ip in AWS account, which I will use in amezon-instance-ip? Please help me a bit on this,

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the help Reut, your suggestions helped me to narrow things down. (I wasn't completely off track).

I finally figured out that my issue was I needed to change the bind_ip config variable in my mongodb.conf file. The bind_IP variable was set (by default) to 127.0.0.1. This prevents remote connections from making their way to the db.

I've since changed that to 0.0.0.0 to allow remote connections.